App created in Visual FoxPro 7 moved to new server but certain reports no longer print
I inherited an old application using Visual FoxPro 7 compiled with a 4GL (I think it was called Blacksmith or something like that)  The Developer retired and left the country and we do not have the source code.
Our issue is that we moved the application to new hardware (and from Win Server 2012 to Win Server 2016 in the process.
The application runs fine, but certain reports fail with a very generic error message.
If I run the application from the new hardware, but point to the old server it prints fine.
But running it with the database on the new local server does not.
I'm thinking about a bad / missing DLL as a possibility but am not sure what DLL's to look for.
or it may not be a DLL issue at all.
Any ideas on where to look?
We Copied all the Directories that had FoxPro files to the new server and the Drive letter mapping is the same.

What's the error message?

That reminds me the classic printer driver problem. Try using printer drivers that ship with windows itself. (BTW to my experience, win7 was better on windows server 2012 compared to 2016).
